# Setup Route Controller Only That Affect To Method

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I have project that use pure **CI**. Now I want migrate to **CI HMVC**. Found problem in **route**.

For example, this is the directory

```
- config
-- routes.php
- applications
-- modules
--- moduleA
---- controllers
------ login.php
--- moduleB
---- controllers
------ anothercontroller.php
```

In **login.php**, I have 2 methods, `index()` and `test()`.
In *config > routes.php*, I defined

```
 $route['login'] = 'moduleA/login';
```

Then, I open `localhost/CI/login`, page successfully opened.
But, when I open `localhost/CI/login/test`, its return **404**.
I must define `$route['login/test'] = 'moduleA/login/test'` to open my test method.
Is there another way that I just define controller only instead define method? I have *>50 method* and that's need more effort.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [the CI Manual for routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) it is possible to use wildcards or even regex or in your routing.

This would be something applicable to your question:

```
$route['login/(:any)'] = 'moduleA/login/$1';
```

Comment: Omg it's works! If method has parameter, just add again like `$route['login/(:any)'] = 'moduleA/login/$1';` . Thank you very much